# Full image with aspect ratio in a circular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put together a profile page and want image inside a `div` which is circular. I want image to retain its aspect ratio. Dimensions of image are unknown and user can upload any image size.

Following is the code:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
 $('.profile-img').find('img').each(function(){
  var imgClass = (this.width/this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
 })
})
```

```css
.profile-img{
    
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px silver;
}
.profile-img img.tall {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.profile-img img.wide {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}​
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-img" class="profile-img">
  <img src="http://i.enrolin.in/img/profile2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the following error using jQuery 1.3.1:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (F || "").split is not a function
```

Thus I changed to the latest available version (2.1.1).

```js
$(window).load(function () {
  $('.profile-img img').addClass(function () {
    return $(this).width() / $(this).height() > 1 ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  });
});
```

```css
.profile-img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px silver;
}
.profile-img img.tall {
    width: 100%;
}
.profile-img img.wide {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-img" class="profile-img">
  <img src="http://i.enrolin.in/img/profile2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following sets either height or width for image depending on the value of image width and height.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.profile-img').find('img').each(function() {
    if(this.width / this.height > 1)
      this.height = $(this).parent().height();
    else
      this.width = $(this).parent().width();
  });
});
```

```css
.profile-img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-img" class="profile-img">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kpOL.png" />
</div>
<div id="profile-img-2" class="profile-img">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIVkh.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: hello Rejith, Thanks for answering but the code is still not working with my image. Don't know why is it. See updated question.